en-IN Streaming Transcription Doesn't work in Google STT
Im using Google Cloud Services for Transcription of Audio coming via microphone, Where I have created a recognizer with parameters: global=Long=en-In. While testing, it doesn't even return any single transcription or word! But with another recognizer with global=short=en-IN as parameters, it works. Could anyone assist me in sorting this out?

import queue
import threading
import time

import audioop
import pyaudio

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "xxxxxxx"

# Audio recording parameters
RATE = 8000
CHUNK = int(RATE / 25)  # 20ms


class MicrophoneStream:
    """Opens a recording stream as a generator yielding the audio chunks."""

    def __init__(self: object, rate: int = RATE, chunk: int = CHUNK) -> None:
        """The audio -- and generator -- is guaranteed to be on the main thread."""
        self._rate = rate
        self._chunk = chunk

        # Create a thread-safe buffer of audio data
        self._buff = queue.Queue()
        self.closed = True

    def __enter__(self: object) -> object:
        self._audio_interface = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self._audio_stream = self._audio_interface.open(
            format=pyaudio.paInt16,
            # The API currently only supports 1-channel (mono) audio
            google api link goes here
            channels=1,
            rate=self._rate,
            input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=self._chunk,
            # Run the audio stream asynchronously to fill the buffer object.
            # This is necessary so that the input device's buffer doesn't
            # overflow while the calling thread makes network requests, etc.
            stream_callback=self._fill_buffer,
        )

        self.closed = False

        return self

    def __exit__(
            self: object,
            type: object,
            value: object,
            traceback: object,
    ) -> None:
        """Closes the stream, regardless of whether the connection was lost or not."""
        self._audio_stream.stop_stream()
        self._audio_stream.close()
        self.closed = True
        # Signal the generator to terminate so that the client's
        # streaming_recognize method will not block the process termination.
        self._buff.put(None)
        self._audio_interface.terminate()

    def _fill_buffer(
            self: object,
            in_data: object,
            frame_count: int,
            time_info: object,
            status_flags: object,
    ) -> object:
        """Continuously collect data from the audio stream, into the buffer.

        Args:
            in_data: The audio data as a bytes object
            frame_count: The number of frames captured
            time_info: The time information
            status_flags: The status flags

        Returns:
            The audio data as a bytes object
        """
        data = audioop.lin2ulaw(in_data, 2)
        self._buff.put(data)
        return None, pyaudio.paContinue

    def generator(self: object) -> object:
        """Generates audio chunks from the stream of audio data in chunks.

        Args:
            self: The MicrophoneStream object

        Returns:
            A generator that outputs audio chunks.
        """
        count = 1
        while not self.closed:
            count += 1
            # Use a blocking get() to ensure there's at least one chunk of
            # data, and stop iteration if the chunk is None, indicating the
            # end of the audio stream.
            chunk = self._buff.get()
            if chunk is None:
                return
            data = [chunk]

            # if count >= 100:
            #     break

            # Now consume whatever other data's still buffered.
            while True:
                try:
                    chunk = self._buff.get(block=False)
                    if chunk is None:
                        return
                    data.append(chunk)
                except queue.Empty:
                    break

            yield b"".join(data)

def main_eng():
    client1 = SpeechClient()

    print("Speak Eng...")
    while True:
        with MicrophoneStream(RATE, CHUNK) as stream:
            audio_generator = stream.generator()
            audio_requests = (
                cloud_speech_types.StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio=audio) for audio in audio_generator
            )

            adaptation = cloud_speech_types.SpeechAdaptation(
                phrase_sets=[
                    cloud_speech_types.SpeechAdaptation.AdaptationPhraseSet(
                        phrase_set='projects/xxxxxxxx/locations/global/phraseSets/adaptations-en'
                    )
                ]
            )

            recognition_config = cloud_speech_types.RecognitionConfig(
                explicit_decoding_config=cloud_speech_types.ExplicitDecodingConfig(encoding='LINEAR16',
                                                                                   sample_rate_hertz=8000,
                                                                                   audio_channel_count=1),
                language_codes=["en-IN"],
                model="long",
                adaptation=adaptation
            )

            # print(recognition_config)

            streaming_config = cloud_speech_types.StreamingRecognitionConfig(
                config=recognition_config,
                streaming_features=cloud_speech_types.StreamingRecognitionFeatures(interim_results=True)
            )
            config_request = cloud_speech_types.StreamingRecognizeRequest(
                recognizer="projects/xxxxxxx/locations/global/recognizers/abc-en-long",
                streaming_config=streaming_config,
            )

            def requests(config: cloud_speech_types.RecognitionConfig, audio: list) -> list:
                yield config
                yield from audio

            # Transcribes the audio into text
            responses_iterator = client1.streaming_recognize(
                requests=requests(config_request, audio_requests)
            )

            responses = []
            for response in responses_iterator:
                responses.append(response)
                for result in response.results:
                    # print(result)
                    if result.alternatives and result.is_final:
                        transcriptB = result.alternatives[0].transcript
                        print(f"Transcript: from Eng: {transcriptB}")

I tried the above given code with en-IN recognizer with short model, it worked. For other languages too it worked.
